# WildFly Deployment Error - DeploymentUnitProcessingException

Tags: java, wildfly

Whenever I'm trying to deploy some `.war` file using `wildfly`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to get manifest for deployment "C"/ProgramFiles (x86)/wildfly-19.1.0.Final/bin/content/<FILENAME>.war/WEB-INF//lib/xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar"

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Please help.

Comment: Possibly just a corrupt jar. I'd rebuild your app as a first step, after having cleaned local ressource if appropriate depending on your build process

Answer (score 0):

Your jar is signed, unsigned it as iirc you need all the jars to be signed properly for this to work.